# How can I update state after array manipulation aka .reduce() with hooks useEffect, useState?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, reduce, react-hooks

I get data from firebase in useEffect.

In useEffect, I store my data (which is an array) in a state using useState.

I want to use this data in my rfc render method but first need to reduce() it. I tried to reduce it in original useEffect (the same where I am fetching the data), in a other useEffect, or even in my render method.

None of these could actually make it. My accumulator argument stays empty in my reduce function. Please, I really need some help on this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Grid, Paper, Typography, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from '@material-ui/core'
import firebase from './../firebase'

const db = firebase.firestore()

export default function Scores(props) {

    let { match } = props
    let [currentEvent, setcurrentEvent] = useState(null)
    let [records, setRecords] = useState([])
    let [data, setdata] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("effet 1")
        db.collection('events').doc(match.params.id)
          .onSnapshot(doc => {

            setcurrentEvent(currentEvent = { ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id })
            setRecords(records = doc.data().records)
          })

      }, [])

      useEffect(() => {
            console.log(records)

          let x = records.reduce((result, record) => {
              console.log(record)
            result[record.user] = result[record.user] || []
            result[record.user].push(record.time.seconds)
            console.log(result)
            return result
        }, [])
          console.log(x)
          setdata(x)

      }, [records])

      if (!currentEvent) {
          return (<h1>data loading ...</h1>)
      }

      return (
          <Paper style={{margin: 8, padding: 8}}>
              <Typography variant='h4'>
                {data.length}
              </Typography>

              <Typography>

              </Typography>


              <Table >
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Participant</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">run 1</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">run 2</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">run 3</TableCell>

                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>

                </TableBody>
            </Table>

          </Paper>
      )
}

/*
useEffect(() => {
          console.log("hi")
          console.log(records)
        let data = records.reduce((result, record) => {
            result[record.user] = result[record.user] || []
            result[record.user].push(record.time.seconds)
            console.log('coucou')
            return result
        }, [])
        setRecords(records = 'coucou')
      }, [])

*/
```

Comment: could you show an example of data that you get from firebase?

Comment: It is just an array of object. I can console.log "records" at the start of the useEffect hook, so my data is there. I can console.log the end result of my manipulation over it  just before useState is called. That's it. After that, something is wrong.

Comment: Please, add an example. This will help to give you a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with `.reduce()` function. You pass an empty array as an initial value to `reduce`. If `record.user` is a string, then you try to add to array value with a string index. That's why you have an empty result. Change the second argument from empty array `[]` to empty object `{}`

Comment: Oh thank you so much !!!! Now I get some value back !!!! But I don't understand how come I could console.log the result using an empty array and getting back my array full of data ??? But not getting to state ... 
Can you explain why an empty array cannot work ?

Comment: And what if I want an array back instead of an object ? I sure can translate it but ...

Comment: @user1859295 from JS documentation "Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers". If you want to get an array instead of an object, use `Object.values(data)` after `reduce`.

Comment: Yes, indeed !!! Thank you very much !!! How can I accept your answer ? You saved my time so much ! :)

Comment: @user1859295 You are welcome. You could click a check mark from the left side of my answer :)